# jquery .each makes two loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

here's the problem:
 I have a function that populates a list with links but the $.each function makes two loops through the linkList object and populates the container twice (2*2=4  items instead of 2) can somebody explain why?

here's the link list:

```
var linkList = {
    link1:["Title","Source","http://google.com","file.pdf"],
    link2:["Title2","Source2","http://google.com","file.pdf"]
};
```

and here is the function:

```
function injectLinks(){

    $.each(linkList, function(i,item) {

        var title = item[0];
        var source = item[2];
        var extern = item[3];


        $('#linkListView').append('\
                <li>\
                    <a rel="external" href="'+extern+'">\
                            <h3>'+title+'</h3><p>'+source+'</p>\
                    </a>\
                </li>\
            ');
        });



}
```

Comment: It doesn't do that, so the problem must be that you're calling the function twice.

Comment: Do you want to populate only one record?

Comment: It makes 2 loops , simply because u have 2 items in the array :)

Comment: it makes a new loop after first loop, which puts 4 items in container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem, actually the populating function was called inside of a $document.ready function which was called once DOM is ready and another time after the populating function finished its work (DOM manipulation calls the document ready function) that's why I had double population. Thanks for your help.

So I used this technique:

```
var pageInitialized = false;

$(function(){
    if(pageInitialized) return;
    pageInitialized = true;
    //do things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went through your code and found that actually its looping twice and it populates the container with two items only but since you have a `<h3>` tag inside the `<li>`, it creates a new line and it seems like its looping 2*2=4 times.

Here is the modified code at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fRNtq/2/)**.